# How to associate a project with a quality profile in Sonarqube

Tags: rest, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonar webapi to associate a project with a quality profile but not able to do it. On every run of sonar-scanner it is associating default quality profile.

This is the code snippet:

```
curl -k -X POST --insecure -H “X-Auth-Token:XXX” -d "language=py" -d "qualityProfile=test_profile" -d “project=test_1.0” https://sonartest.xxx.com/api/qualityprofiles/add_project
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have administrative access and followed the webapi of Version `6.7.3 (build 38370)`

Comment: Your `"` and `'` are looking weird (`“”` & `‘’`). Check that those are not formatted in the original call. They should be plain `"` and `'` and not those formatted version word, Mail-Clients or other texteditors like to insert

Comment: @Hecke29 I have reformatted my code to use (""). I am still not able to associate my quality profile to project. I am using SCANNER: 'Sonar-Scanner-3.2.0.1227'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got some help from Soanrqube community. I need to remove X-Auth-Token from code. It should be something like this

```
curl -u ur_token: -X POST -d language=py -d qualityProfile=test_profile -d projectKey=${params.ProjectName} https://sonar-url.com/api/qualityprofiles/add_project
```